# cannot generate credentials for Google assistant

Tags: python, google-assistant-sdk

I am trying to turn a Raspberry Pi 3 into a Google Assistant. I thought it would be fun but now I am stuck.

I am trying to generate credentials and the code I am putting in is the following:

`google-oauthlib-tool --scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/assistant-sdk-prototype \ --scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gcm \ --save --headless --client-secrets /path/to/credentials.json`

I am continually getting extra argument feedback for `--save` `--scope`. You may have to go back to basics for me to get it! IDK, everything else seems to flow except for this last part.

Answer (score 0):

Try with just

> google-oauthlib-tool --client-secrets credentials.json --scope
>   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/assistant-sdk-prototype --save
>   --headless

With the good path for json file.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/env/bin/google-oauthlib-tool", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/click/core.py", line 722, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/click/core.py", line 697, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/click/core.py", line 895, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)

Comment: File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/click/core.py", line 535, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google_auth_oauthlib/tool/__main__.py", line 100, in main
    scopes=scope
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google_auth_oauthlib/flow.py", line 171, in from_client_secrets_file
    with open(client_secrets_file, 'r') as json_file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/pi/downloads/client_secrets.json'

Comment: That is what I get when I put the information in. It seems like my file path is wrong or something. Can anyone make sense of this??

Comment: No such file or directory: '/home/pi/downloads/client_secrets.json'   Are you sure your file is at good place ?

Comment: This file is made by google authentification for python lib use, so it's not normal to have it in a "download" folder. The downloaded file is called "credentials.json". Wich one procedure are you using ?

Comment: That is a great question. When you "download" the .json from google cloud platform, that is where it stores it. Is there a different file I should be looking for? In the online "how to" it shows to point towards the /home/pi/downloads folder. Should recreate a new "Ga" project or redownload the json file?

Comment: For me I m seeing 'Make sure this file is located in /home/pi' and 'Do not rename this file' on the "how to". I m using this one https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/library/python/embed/register-device

Comment: IForgetMyPassword--You have been a huge help. After you told me the file was in the wrong place, I pasted it in /home/pi and the authentication worked. Still had issues with mic/speakers but was able to work through those. Honestly, it lead to paying attention to detail and copy/paste the code. I also started from scratch with a new project. Thank you so much for your help. This has truly been a learning experience.Also, several failures caused me to sit down and learn about what the commands meant so this experience has defined "learning curve" ha ha ha

Comment: Not your fault, even the official tutorial is buggy and vague, and to help you, you have 10 differents tutorials, each one with differents commands. And there is changes at all updates, so most of them are out of date. In any case, good luck with this wonderful library ^^.